# How can I use \iow_now:Nx with umlauts/unicode?

Tags: unicode, expl3, expansion, write

I do some file writing with `expl3` but also need the `Nx` version, which collides with the usage of umlauts. The `Nn` version handles the umlauts correctly but doesn’t expand the token list for writing it to the file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{csvsimple,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\iow_new:N \tobi_file_iow

\tl_const:Nn \c_tobi_something_tl { Something }

\AtBeginDocument {
   \iow_open:Nn \tobi_file_iow { \jobname-file.csv }
}

\AtEndDocument {
   \iow_close:N \tobi_file_iow
   \par\bigskip
   \csvautotabular { \jobname-file.csv }
}

\NewDocumentCommand { \writetofile } { m } {
%   \iow_now:Nn \tobi_file_iow { \c_tobi_something_tl , #1 }
   \iow_now:Nx \tobi_file_iow { \c_tobi_something_tl , #1 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Test \writetofile{Test}

Täst \writetofile{Täst}
Täst \writetofile{Südwand}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to use `Nx` with umlauts written correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are using pdfTeX, otherwise you wouldn't have issues with Unicode.

There are a few options, depending on what precisely you want to do.

If you don't want the argument to expand *at all*, then you can use `\exp_not:n {#1}` to prevent `\write` from messing up the active UTF-8 tokens:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand { \writetofile } { m }
  { \iow_now:Nx \tobi_file_iow { \c_tobi_something_tl , \exp_not:n {#1} } }
```

Though if you want to expand `#1`, in case there are macros in there, then you can use `\text_expand:n`:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand { \writetofile } { m }
  { \iow_now:Nx \tobi_file_iow { \c_tobi_something_tl , \text_expand:n {#1} } }
```

As for `\c_tobi_something_tl`, if you want it to expand fully, then use it as you did.  If you want it to expand to its contents, then use `\exp_not:V`:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand { \writetofile } { m }
  { \iow_now:Nx \tobi_file_iow { \exp_not:V \c_tobi_something_tl , \text_expand:n {#1} } }
```

or if you want full expansion without braking with Unicode, then `\text_expand:n` again:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand { \writetofile } { m }
  { \iow_now:Nx \tobi_file_iow { \text_expand:n { \c_tobi_something_tl } , \text_expand:n {#1} } }
```

Comment: Thanks. `\text_expand:n` was the solution for my case :-)